react-toastify "Cannot destructure property 'position' of 'u.props' as it is undefined"
I'm super struggling with react-toastify and an error I'm getting randomly, after browning different pages in my application it just fails suddenly and crashes whole app. The error I'm getting:
"Cannot destructure property 'position' of 'u.props' as it is undefined".

Its like its works initially fine but when I'm starting to switch pages and then the snackbar renders it just crashes.
